# AVPlayer won't play a different format

Tags: ios, singleton, avplayer

I am implementing a player with `AVPlayer`, which will play videos from a URL. This URL can be for "fixed-length" videos (that have a predetermined duration) and live videos (whose duration is unknown/not defined).

The fixed-length URLs I am using link to .mp4 files (using H264 codec), while the live videos have a .m3u8 extensions (but also H264).

I can play a number of .m3u8 URLs, but when I try to play the .mp4, it won't load.
However, if I start the app and play a .mp4 URL first, I can play other .mp4 URLs, but I can't switch to the .m3u8.
Both formats play fine, but there some issue when I switch from one to another.

These are the methods I use to instantiate and "clean" the player:

```
- (void)prepareAndPlayAutomatically:(BOOL)playAutomatically {
  currentItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:videoURL];
  [[self player] replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem:currentItem];
  [self.layer addSublayer:[self playerLayer]];

  [[self player] addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"rate" options:0 context:nil];

  [[self player] seekToTime:kCMTimeZero];

  if (playAutomatically) {
    [[self player] play];
  }
}

- (void)clean {
  [[self player] pause];
  [[self player] seekToTime:kCMTimeZero];
  [[self player] replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem:nil];
  [[self player] removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"rate"];
  [self removeFromSuperview];
}
```

`[self player]` will return a singleton AVPlayer instance;
`[self playerLayer]` will also return a singleton AVPlayerLayer instance;

```
- (AVPlayer *)player {
  static dispatch_once_t once;
  static AVPlayer *player;
  dispatch_once(&once, ^{
    player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:currentItem];
  });
  return player;
}

- (AVPlayerLayer *)playerLayer {
  static dispatch_once_t once;
  static AVPlayerLayer *playerLayer;
  dispatch_once(&once, ^{
    playerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:[self player]];
  });
  return playerLayer;
}
```

I've narrowed down the problem to these singletons. If I remove the singleton pattern, no problem will occur, and I am able to play both kinds of videos.

Is there anything else I am supposed to do when I "clean" the player?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that AVPlayer class is not intended for reuse for items with different video compositions.

From the docs on [[AVPlayer replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem:] method](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayer_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/AVPlayer/replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem:):

> Special Considerations
>
> The new item must have the same compositor as the item it replaces, or
>   have no compositor.

Comment: It doesn't solve the problem, but it explains why it happens. Solution: no singleton pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I too ran into same problem recently. I solved it by maintaining 2 instances of the AVQueuePlayer - One to play Mp4 and other for M3u8. 
And switched between these players by hiding one player view and showing the other based on the video format (Mp4/M3u8).